# PDO Prepared Statement does not UPDATE table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am developing an ORM based on PDO, for tables that don't have unique ID fields, so when I update or delete, I need to compare to the previous values of the record, and `LIMIT 1`.

When my query finally gets to the database and is executed with the parameters, everything is correct, as confirmed by the general query log, however, **nothing is happening**.

I get no exceptions thrown (`PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` is on), and checking `$stmt->errorInfo()` comes back clean, but `$stmt->rowCount()` returns `0`.

As a sanity check, I opened the log file, copy and pasted the UPDATE query right into Sequel Pro (an OSX MySQL GUI) and executed, and everything worked as expected, updating 1 row.

Why does PDO not update the row, when manually executing an **IDENTICAL** query does?

Comment: Could you perhaps show the code that isn't working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP PDO Prepared statement query not updating record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124294/php-pdo-prepared-statement-query-not-updating-record)

Comment: @Bill: It's not. I checked. The problem there was that they were quoting their placeholders.

Comment: Solved. My code generates `= NULL` for a WHERE clause, when it should be `IS NULL`. MySQL (for whatever reason) changes `=` to `IS` when it logs it, but not when it executes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that my code generated a query using

```
WHERE `FieldName` = NULL
```

when it should have been

```
WHERE `FieldName` IS NULL
```

When executed by PDO, it kept the `= NULL`, causing no records to be matched, but when MySQL logged it, it logged `IS NULL`, so when I copied/pasted, the query was correct and updated the row.